# Binding an anonymous function to an existing function in PHP

Tags: php, anonymous-function

Is there a way to bind an existing function to an anonymous one in php? Something like

```
$my_func = strip_tags();
```

Or must I half-redefine it, as a sort of anonymous wrapper, with the proper arguments and return value?

I tried googling this, but I suppose I didn't correctly suss the proper search phrase, as I didn't find results on the first page.

**Edit** I'm making a sort of function pipeline(?) where I can pass data and functions, and I want to pass functions as variables. I would like to keep the syntax the same and be able to use `$output = $function($data)` without having to write a bunch of anonymous wrappings for native functions. Also I would like to avoid using `call_user_func` so I don't have to re-write my existing code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple.

```
$my_func = strip_tags(...); # string 'strip_tags' before PHP 8.1.0
$output = $my_func($data);
```

- https://php.net/callable
- [PHP First class callable syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.first_class_callable_syntax.php)

Answer (score 3):

You can bind the function by it's name. Have a look at the [callable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) Interface from php

Code from the manual mentioned above

```
<?php 

// An example callback function
function my_callback_function() {
    echo 'hello world!';
}

// An example callback method
class MyClass {
    static function myCallbackMethod() {
        echo 'Hello World!';
    }
}

// Type 1: Simple callback
call_user_func('my_callback_function'); 

// Type 2: Static class method call
call_user_func(array('MyClass', 'myCallbackMethod')); 

// Type 3: Object method call
$obj = new MyClass();
call_user_func(array($obj, 'myCallbackMethod'));

// Type 4: Static class method call (As of PHP 5.2.3)
call_user_func('MyClass::myCallbackMethod');

// Type 5: Relative static class method call (As of PHP 5.3.0)
class A {
    public static function who() {
        echo "A\n";
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public static function who() {
        echo "B\n";
    }
}

call_user_func(array('B', 'parent::who')); // A
?>
```